# How to animate grid elements swapping places?

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations

I have 4 divs in a grid and a button that swaps div number 1 and 4. I wanted to add animation between blocks 1 and 4 but I don't have any idea how to do it. I need it to make cup and ball game, so animation on swapping places is pretty important.

I've tried to add `transition` on the container id and creating a keyframe animation that changes places on grid and activate them by JS but it didn't work.

I would appreciate any help.

```js
let btt = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
let tab = document.getElementsByClassName("grid");

let change = () => {
  tab[0].style.order = 1;
  tab[3].style.order = -1;
};

btt = addEventListener("click", change);
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 250px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 250px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  place-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button>swap</button>
<section id="container">
  <div class="grid" id="g1">1</div>
  <div class="grid" id="g2">2</div>
  <div class="grid" id="g3">3</div>
  <div class="grid" id="g4">4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you mean `btt[0].addEventListener(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the animation inside the JavaScript code in order to give it to the div number 1 and 4 when the swap action is started.
After the animation I disables transitions to instantly reset positions and change their grid order without further animation and i did that by forcing a layout recalculation and then re-enabling transitions it ensures smooth future animations without unintended effects during the swap.

I hop this answer your question and help you.

but take into consideration this code is not the best solution and I think it should be a better solution than my. try to make it more dynamic if you have more than 4 div.

**NOTE: I did the swap for one time and in one direction.**

*Finally sorry about my English it is not good.*

```js
let btn = document.querySelector("button");

let change = () => {
  const grid1 = document.getElementById('g1');
  const grid2 = document.getElementById('g2');
  const grid3 = document.getElementById('g3');
  const grid4 = document.getElementById('g4');

  grid1.style.transform = `translate(260px, 260px)`;
  grid4.style.transform = `translate(-260px, -260px)`;

  setTimeout(() => {
    grid1.style.transition = 'none';
    grid4.style.transition = 'none';

    grid1.style.transform = '';
    grid4.style.transform = '';

    grid1.style.order = 4;
    grid2.style.order = 2;
    grid3.style.order = 3;
    grid4.style.order = 1;

    void grid1.offsetWidth;
    void grid4.offsetWidth;

    setTimeout(() => {
      grid1.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease';
      grid4.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease';
    }, 10);

  }, 500);
};

btn.addEventListener("click", change);
```

```css
    #container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 250px);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 250px);
      grid-gap: 10px;
      place-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .grid {
      transition: transform 0.5s ease;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<button>swap</button>
<section id="container">
  <div class="grid" id="g1">1</div>
  <div class="grid" id="g2">2</div>
  <div class="grid" id="g3">3</div>
  <div class="grid" id="g4">4</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ok this works but in my original project i have 8 divs in 2x4 and i have to make about 10 combinations of divs being shuffled  and i wish that i could find better solution, but for a school project it should be fine so thank you very much.